# testing.postgres failing with "Command not found: initdb"

Tags: python, postgresql, python-unittest

I'm trying to run some unit tests on a python function that updates a database.
I'm attempting to use testing.postgres to create a local database upon which to carry out the tests.
I have the following code for my unit test:

```
from unittest import TestCase
import testing.postgresql
import psycopg2
import postgres

class TestCOUDB(TestCase):
    def test_COUDB(self):
        self.postgresql = testing.postgresql.Postgresql(port=7654)
        print(self.postgresql.url())
```

When I run this, I get:

```
Command not found: initdb
```

I have postgres installed in the python environment I'm using but from my limited understanding I'm thinking that testing.postgresql does not know where to find it.
Can anyone help?

Comment: You should try to add `/usr/lib/postgresql/{version}/bin/` to `PATH`

Comment: Thanks, I'm on Windows executing in a Python virtual environment. Python is already on the windows PATH. I've tried adding a PYTHONPATH variable to Windows that points to the site-packages location of Postgres, but I get the same error. Is there some PATH I should be setting within the environment?

Comment: I believe you will need to install postgres (not the python package) as well. And add its binaries directory to `PATH`

Comment: I've installed postgres into the virtualenv, but it still gives the error. The problem is  I don't know how to get testing.postgres to see that installastion within the virtualenv.